# The application has been signed with a provisioning profile which does not include any devices

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-provisioning

Trying to run application on my iPhone via usb cable

error 'The application has been signed with a provisioning profile which does not include any devices.'

I've added my device on the developer portal and re-downloaded the provisioning profiles both from xCode and Visual Studio

Comment: Hi, could you see your iPhone in the device list of Visual Studio? And you also could share the screenshot of error, I will check that. You also could have a try with [Automatic Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=macos) to check whether can work.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos :

1. Go to Apple developer accounts window in Visual Studio.
   Mac: Visual Studio > Preferences > Apple Developer Account
   Windows: Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts
2. Select the team and click View Details…
3. **Verify that the new profile appears in the Provisioning Profiles list. You may need to restart Visual Studio to refresh the list.**
4. Click Download All Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the provisioning profile, creating it again and re-downloading it.
Maybe I did something wrong the first time, I'm not sure but it works now